# Regex Filtering Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, filter

I am filtering using a Regex on an array but I want to modify it so it can search even when there are whitespaces:

```
 transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter){
      console.log(items);
      return items;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(items)){
      return items;
    }

    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

      if (defaultFilter) {
       
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi',).test(item[keyName],)) || filter[keyName] == "", true),);
      }
      else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but I am not sure how to add the ('\s') expression to allow for whitespaces.

Comment: you can try replacing whitespace from `item[keyName]`. Something like `item[keyName].replace(/\s/g, '')`

Comment: This removes the whole item array which is displayed in a table format in Angular

Answer (score 0):

To pick up on @Sonu's comment:

Remove all white spaces from `item[keyName]` before applying the `.test()` with `filter[keyName]`:

```
...
return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName].replace(/\s/g,''));
...
```

Or, in case you only want to remove *surrounding*  white space you could to:

```
...
return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName].trim());
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I try that way, the item array which actually displays tables for each element in Angular all disappears. I just want to be able to search even including whitespaces so maybe it needs to be somehow applied to filter[keyName]

Comment: Can you give us a few examples of your key values (`filter[keyName]`) and target strings (`item[keyName]`) that you want to have as matches or non-matches?

Comment: So I am filtering on two properties (course code) and example strings include 4-8 digit numbers (such as "1021", "3319" and the other property I am filtering on is course name ("ANTHROPOLOGY FOR BEGINNERS") and itek[keyname] include both of these properties and many other properties about the course in an object for each course.

Comment: In which variables/properties will I find your "course code" or your "course name"? It would be very helpful if you could edit your question and define the arrays `filterKeys` and `items` there (at least with some of their elements). And how do you want your filtering to work? Positives and negatives ...

Comment: Basically, I need to do a soft search so it matches even if there are some whitespaces and even if 1-2 characters are wrong